# Cannot set the background color of TopAppBar in jetpack compose (There is no backgroundColor property)

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, background-color

I am trying to set the background color of TopAppBar using jetpack compose but I am unable to do it. All the posts on the internet use a property called backgroundColor to change the background color but I cannot see any property like that. I also tried using Modifier.background() to change the color but nothing changed. Can someone tell how to change the background color of TopAppBar?

I tried Modifier.background() and backgroundColor property (This property is just not there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TopAppBar` have `colors` as a parameter.

You can set the color like this,

```
CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
    ),
    // Other parameters
)
```

Since the question does not have a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I have shared an example using `CenterAlignedTopAppBar` from [Material 3](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/overview).